# Register pjsip account using Tls setting in pjsua

Tags: android, voip, pjsip

I am using Pjusa for Voip, I have done communication through UDP and TCP but could not communitcate through TLS setting`

```
TlsConfig tlsConfig = new TlsConfig();
File cacheDir = new File(ctx.getCacheDir(), "ca");
InputStream input = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.ca);
tlsConfig.setCaListFile(cacheDir.getPath());
input = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.secure);
cacheDir = new File(ctx.getCacheDir(), "secure");
tlsConfig.setCertFile(cacheDir.getPath());
tlsConfig.setMethod(pjsip_ssl_method.PJSIP_SSLV23_METHOD);`
```

I have attached CaListFile and setCertFile files like that method  and that setting working but When I establish a call then I found error like that

> tlsc0x9e7db014  TLS connect() error: Connection refused [code=120111]
>   tsx0x9d945864  Failed to send Request msg INVITE/cseq=25416 (tdta0x9d991000)! err=120111 (Connection refused)

In IOS I found some more setting for TLS , but could not implement in PJSUA
any one can help me out how to use that piece of code in android in PJSUA library

```
 pj_sockaddr_in remote;
pjsip_transport *transport;
remote.sin_family = pj_AF_INET();
remote.sin_zero_len   =   0;
remote.sin_addr.s_addr = pj_inet_addr(@"xxx.xx.xx.xx").s_addr;
remote.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
bzero(&(remote.sin_zero),sizeof(remote.sin_zero));

app_config->cfg.use_srtp = PJMEDIA_SRTP_MANDATORY;
app_config->cfg.srtp_secure_signaling = 1;
```

thanks in advance

Comment: pjmedia_srtp_use model might be used, but how??

Comment: you need sert in the client? for authentication?

Comment: yes , i want communication secure, I authenticate with CAListFile and Sertificate File

Comment: @Munir Hi, What is difference between setCaListFile and setCertFile. Where is Client Certificate and Server?

Comment: From where I can get the certificates to use in the solution? Can you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TlsConfig tlsConfig = new TlsConfig();

tlsConfig.setCertFile(certFile);

sipTpConfig.setTlsConfig(tlsConfig);
tlsConfig.setCaListFile(caListFile);
```

I did R&D from web searching and reading document of SIP and PJSIP, then I find the sluotion for accountConfig for PJMEDIA_SRTP_MANDATORY and setSrtpSecureSignaling(1) by that way provided below

```
accCfg.getMediaConfig().setSrtpUse(pjmedia_srtp_use.PJMEDIA_SRTP_MANDATORY);
accCfg.getMediaConfig().setSrtpSecureSignaling(1);
```

Hence TLS working with CAListFile and CertificateFile

Comment: Hi, What is difference between setCaListFile and setCertFile. Where is Client Certificate and Server?

Comment: From where I can get the certificates to use in the solution?

Comment: @MeghaParmar you will get these certificates from Back-end server just like Asterisk, where these files are created and shared front-end Mobile Apps

Comment: @GensaGames please use mentioned link https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Secure+Calling+Tutorial to create required files

Comment: my problem is how do I load the file into the project? Is it a path, or the content (string) of the file?